# Where are Windows Key shortcuts defined? Specifically for Snipping Tool

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-server-2016

On Windows Server 2016, the Snipping Tool comes up in capture mode when I invoke Windows + Shift + S.  In Windows 10, I can mimic this behavior by running "snippingtool.exe /clip" but this does not work in Windows Server 2016.

I'd like to figure out what Windows is doing when the Windows + Shift + S keystroke is used because I want to enter this same capture mode directly from a Powershell script.

I'd think this is somewhere visible in the Registry as I recall it being so in old version of Windows CE but I cannot find the equivalent in Windows Server.

Where is this information stored?

Answer (score -1):

In typical Windows apps, keyboard shortcuts are hard-wired directly into the apps. There is no configuration database where they can be remapped. (Until such a feature is explicitly implemented in the application, like you can find for example in Microsoft Word.)

The most notable exception to this is Windows Explorer. It serves as a proxy between the user and built-in auxiliary tools. If you exit it*, you can see that many (but not all) keyboard shortcuts stopped working. This way you can quickly determine which keyboard shortcuts are served by this system application. But even if you find that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is answered by Windows Explorer, there is no table where you can *configure* it.

If you really need to introduce the shortcut where it is missing (and also potentially overwrite the existing one), then use the [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) like the following (note: full path may be required)

```
+#s::Run snippingtool.exe /clip
```

If you find out how various internal Windows actions are launched (some can be invoked via calling DLL methods or command line etc.), you can create more shortcuts on your own – example:

```
+#d::Run C:\WINDOWS\system32\control.exe desk.cpl`,@0`,3  ; opens Desktop control panel
```

__

*) To exit, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click the task bar and select **Exit Explorer** from the context menu. To launch Windows Explorer again, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and using menu **File** > **Run new task**, launch `explorer` app again by typing its name and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I'm not really interested in remapping it, so much as reverse engineering what it is doing.  I want to invoke the same action that it does.  For what it's worth, exiting explorer causes Windows + Shift + S to do a different action, interestingly enough.  This implies the logic to launch snipping tool in the capture mode lives in Explorer itself